# Changing from a generic to a tuned atlas version

Tags: python, numpy, scipy, atlas

I have Fedora 16 with the atlas-sse3 package installed and used by numpy and scipy. All 3 packages are from the distribution's repository. My question is, if i download a source rpm of the Atlas library and compile it to fit my hardware better, do i need to compile numpy and scipy also against the new installed Atlas version?

Answer (score 0):

On my computer I compiled SciPy using the newest `lapack`[from here[(http://www.netlib.org/lapack/), which contains its own `blas` library. I guess for `atlas` the process will be similar:

1. compile the `blas` library. Go to `SRC` and run make
2. compile the `lapack` library. Rename `make.inc.example` to `make.inc` and edit it if necessary (the optimization flag -O2 should be there, and it can be changed to -O3 for the most optimized case). Run`make`

Then, in the scipy source folder:

1. rename `site.cfg.example` to `site.cfg` and add this (the paths are in Windows format):

   [lapack]
   library_dirs = C:\Users\pfh-castro\Downloads\lapack-3.4.2
   lapack_libs = lapack, tmglib
   [blas]
   library_dirs = C:\Users\pfh-castro\Downloads\lapack-3.4.2
   blas_libs = refblas
2. run `python setup.py config --compiler=mingw32 build --compiler=mingw32 install`

The build version will be in `./build`.

You should also [have a look here](http://www.scipy.org/scipylib/building/windows.html).